# How to remove the elements from the drop down list in ASP.NET automatically based upon the availability of the stock?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net

How to remove the zero stock elements from the drop down list automatically based upon the stock in ASP.NET?[Here is the drop down list from this i would like to remove the elements in zero quantity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZWSO1.jpg)

[image]

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-3">Item</label>
    <div class="col-md-9">
        @*@Html.DropDownList("ItemId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })*@
        <input list="itemsList" name="ItemId" id="ItemId" class="form-control" required style="width:250px;" />
        <datalist id="itemsList">
            @foreach (var item in ViewBag.ItemId)
            {
                <option value="@(item.Text + "---- " + item.Value)"></ option >
            }
    </datalist>
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ItemId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

When you are filling the list in ViewBag in Controller, you can apply the check if stocks>0 than only add the data into that list. Than the list will be of the stock>0.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter zero stock value while populating dropdown from the server.

```
  @foreach (var item in ViewBag.ItemId)
                {
                    if(item.someCheck)
                    {
                      <option value="@(item.Text + "---- " + item.Value)">
                      </ option >
                     }
                }
```

where someCheck is for zero stock.

Answer (score 0):

If the stock information is only available in the item.Text- property you can do this.

```
        @foreach (var item in ViewBag.ItemId)
        {
              string stock = item.Text.Split('(',')')[1];
              if(!stock.Equals("0"))
             {
                  <option value="@(item.Text + "---- " + item.Value)"></ option >
             }
        }
```